# Oracle SQL to Get output like that using cross tabulation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've 2 tables named as **emp** & **emp_history** having records like that-

emp table-

```
emp_ID   ename
e001     abc
e002     pqr
e003     xyz
e004     lmn
```

emp_history table-

```
sid    from_emp     to_emp
01      e001        e002
02      e002        e003
03      e003        e004
04      e004        e004
```

Want to get output ename instead of emp_ID in emp_history table like that-

```
sid    from_emp     to_emp
01      abc         pqr
02      pqr         xyz
03      xyz         lmn
04      lmn         lmn
```

Comment: for me, really irrelevant name is `to_date`, for those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` the `emp` table twice to get those names.

```
select eh.sid,efrom.ename,eto.ename
from emp_history eh
join emp efrom on efrom.emp_id=eh.from_id
join emp eto on eto.emp_id=eh.to_date
```